# Bring tileLayer to front in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

Is it possible to display `tileLayer` on top of all other layers? This means that all other layers are displayed below the `tileLayer`.

Googled all day, but couldn't find definite yes or no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can manipulate the order by simply adding this code:

```
var topPane = map._createPane('leaflet-top-pane', map.getPanes().mapPane);
topPane.appendChild(yourtileLayer.getContainer());
yourtileLayer.setZIndex(5);
```

Comment: I'm getting `map._createPane is not a function` :(

Answer (score 2):

Create a map pane on top of (with a higher `z-index` than) the standard tile pane, and position your tile layer in it.

There is an [entire Lealfet tutorial on the issue](http://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/).

Comment: And yes, one of the examples in the link is exactly the issue I was solving, bring the geo names labels on top of my vector map.